# Can't access correctly frontend, backend and install tool in TYPO3 7.6.14

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have migrated a website, firtable the DB, same name, user and password. Later I copied the website directories, ohter occasions this worked me. But now, with this website the frontend, backend and InstallTool are render in the browser as I show respectively[image] [image]

[image]

I have tried with commands chmod (inclusive 777) and chown, erase and keep the typo3temp content.

Comment: have you erased all files from `typo3temp/`? I assume you have copied also the folder `typo3temp/` where some folders of the origin server are mentioned which does not exist on your target. at least erase `typo3temp/Cache/`.

Answer (score 0):

Check free spase on the server.
If You have linux server try from ssh

```
df -h
```

or clean all "cashe" folder from typo3temp

Comment: Yes, I am using Centos 7. With df command I saw that it uses currently 22%. And when I clened "Cache" folder, frontend and backend show a blank page with a source page empty, and InstallTool page show the same error

Comment: As stated in your last screenshot "session file not writeable" Please have a look at your file and folder permissions and ownership.

Comment: Check Selinux rules try disable selinux
setenforce 0 
If it work you must allow apache write in selinux
setenforce 1  - to enable selinux.

Comment: Check Selinux rules try disable selinux "setenforce 0" If it work you must allow apache write in selinux setenforce 1 - to enable selinux. 
Rules:
https://gitlab.com/snippets/1719031